# Migrating a website with an SQL database from one server to the other

Tags: sql-server, migration

I am new to the servers world and I need to migrate a website with an SQL database in the back from one server to the other...

I have all the files that are needed but I don t know what to do with them ... can someone guide me on where to start even ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simplest method will be to take backup of current database which is used by your application on one server and restore that backup on second server.

Alternatively you can script out whole database and run SQL scripts on another server to recreate same objects. Or create/run SSIS package to move data.

As you can see there are more than one possible way to achieve this, it will be helpful if you give more details about your layout (like sever location, db accessibility methods for server, db size, authentication method used, any special requirements etc)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @JackLock's suggestion, once you script out the database and tables (just the skeletons of them), if you have a Linked Server established, you can do a simple insert into script:

```
INSERT INTO TableNOnNewServer
SELECT *
FROM [LinkedOldServer].[OldDatabase].[OldSchema].[TableNOnOldServer]
```

Granted, this could take a while if you have multiple tables, and quite frankly, restoring a back up would be easier, but it shows you another method of migrating data.

Forgot to add, if you had only one database, you could design a dynamic SQL script where the Table Name could change dynamically, and where the `INSERT INTO` script could go through each table and do it, making it easier.  Something like the below:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO ' + @table + '
SELECT *
FROM [LinkedOldServer].[OldDatabase].[OldSchema]. ' + @table

EXECUTE(@sql)
```

The variable @table would be derived from a table where the names of all the tables are stored.